# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

why does this code not work?

```
def test():   
    e = None
    try:
        raise Exception

    except Exception as e:
        pass

    return e

test()
```

I get this error:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When an exception is caught and bound to a name, the name is cleared following the `try` statement. From the [documentation of the `try` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

```
except E as N:
    foo
```

behaves the same as

```
except E as N:
    try:
        foo
    finally:
        del N
```

So if an exception is caught, `e` no longer exists once `return e` has been reached. This is described as being done to break the reference cycle between the stack frame (which contains a reference to `e`) and the traceback referenced by `e` (which contains a reference to the stack frame).

Comment: Outstanding answer. This shows me how many little things and details are still unknown for me as regards to how Python is implemented.